# How to find a solution for this Riccati equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying the following Riccati equation
$$y' + \frac{y}x + y^2 = \frac{4}{x^2},$$
and I know the following solution

$$y=\frac{a}{x}$$

I need to find a general solution for this equation, and by using the above equation and the following one

$$y' = \frac{-a}{x^2},$$

I was able to write the following equation for the unknown constant $a$:
$$
a^2 = 4
$$

Is this the correct way to find $a$? And if it is so, how do I choose between $a = 2$ and $a = -2$? Thanks

Edit

I assumed $a = 2$ therefore $y = \frac{2}{x}$

$y_1 = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{u}$   and $y_1' = \frac{-2}{x^2}-\frac{u'}{u^2}$

Now I put $y_1$ and $y_1'$ in the first equation

This leads me

$u' -\frac{5}{x}u = 1 $.

I applied integrating factor to find a general solution

$u = -\frac{x}{4}+cx^5$

I put $u$ in $y_1 = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{u}$  and got my final result.

$y = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{\frac{-x}{4} + cx^5}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Check if there is a typo in youir equation

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes I corrected it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Substitute

$$y(x)=\frac{v(x)}{x}$$ then we get

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=\frac{x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}-v(x)}{x^2}$$
and our equation will be

$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{-v(x)^2+4}{x}$$
Can you proceed?
and then
$$\int \frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}}{-v(x)^2+4}dx=\int \frac{1}{x}dx$$

Comment: I just edited my question as I progress further. Could you check it out please again?